# Best explicit bound on $\zeta'(1+it)/\zeta(1+it)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Assume the Riemann hypothesis. We know that
$$\left|\frac{\zeta'(1+it)}{\zeta(1+it)}\right| \leq 2 \log \log t + O(1)$$
(see, e.g., Thm. 13.13 in Montgomery-Vaughan). What is the best explicit bound of this sort in the literature?

Comment: 13.13 where, Titchmarsh?

Comment: I think it's Thm 13.13 of Montgomery and Vaughan, *Multiplicative Number Theory, Vol. I*

Comment: I'm not aware of any explicit bound in existing literature. However, my colleague is currently writing up a paper where as a corollary they obtain $|\zeta'/\zeta(1+it)| \leq 33.65(\log\log{t})^2$ for $t\geq 10^5$

Comment: Maybe related? https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3595 Thm 1.5 and the remark about zeta at the end of the section. This is a bound for the log of the L-function and not its derivative, but maybe the method can be adapted.

Comment: @Aurel Oh, what is in that paper can certainly be adapted from $L$-functions to $\zeta(1+it)$, but I don't see where they bound $L'(1,\chi)/L(1,\chi)$. Also, there seems to be no Theorem 1.5!

Comment: @DanielJohnston That's under RH, surely? One should be able to do better.

Comment: @HAHelfgott Are you looking at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.3595.pdf? Theorem 1.5 is given in section 1.3 starting at the bottom of page 3, and the proof of theorem 1.5 is given in section 5 which starts on page 17. Theorem 1.5 gives a bound on $|L(1,\chi)|$ and $|1//L(1,\chi)|$. The note at the end of the section gives a bound on $|\zeta(1+i\,t)|$ and $|1/\zeta(1+i\,t)|$ assuming $t>10^{10}$ and the RH.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I got confused because there is different numeration for Theorems and Lemmas. But yes, I've read that paper, and contains what you say (in fact a student, a postdoc and I just improved the bound on |1/\zeta(1+it)| a little bit, and weakened the assumptions).